# How to check rabbitMQ connection(health check) up or not?

Tags: bash, docker, rabbitmq

I'm running 4 microservice using docker. Here one service depends on other services. That is why I need to check before using any service other services up or not?

To up all services I'm writing a bash script.
For my working purpose, I am using `sleep`  until up properly rabbitmq.

what is the better solution to check rabbitmq up or not? Until not up rabbitmq I have to wait.
Now for my working pupose i am using like that -

```
# wait for rabbitmq container be ready 
sleep 14
```

This is the docker-compose container for rabbitMQ

```
rabbitmq:
image: 'rabbitmq:3.8.9'
container_name: rabbitmq_dev
restart: always
ports:
  - 5675:5672
environment:
  - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbit
  - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=pass
depends_on:
  - consul
networks:
  - my_networks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think HealthCheck can solve your problem.

Reference links: [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)

Comment: Thanks for me it is working by this test command -

test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]

Answer (score 0):

There is a clean and straightforward way to achieve that with docker compose, by using `healthcheck` in combination with `depends_on`. As in the code snippet below:

```
rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:latest
  container_name: rabbitmq_dev
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 5675:5672
  environment:
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbit
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=pass
  depends_on:
    - consul
  networks:
    - my_networks
  healthcheck:
    test: rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping
    interval: 30s
    timeout: 10s
    retries: 5
    start_period: 10s
```

and in other services you need to add `depends_on`:

```
  your_app:
    ...
    depends_on:
        rabbitmq:
            condition: service_healthy
```